# Error establishing a database connection on wordpress new installation

Tags: apache-2.2, centos6, wordpress, httpd

I am running Apache on CentOS release 6.8 on a vps and am trying to install wordpress.

I editied the wp-config with the correct credentials to the database. Those same credentials work in phpmyadmin and test php scripts run from on the server over ssh.

mysqld and httpd logs are clean.

permissions on the directory of wp stuff is set to 767 recursively.

What am I missing?

wp-config contents:

```
<?php
/**
 * The base configuration for WordPress
 *
 * The wp-config.php creation script uses this file during the
 * installation. You don't have to use the web site, you can
 * copy this file to "wp-config.php" and fill in the values.
 *
 * This file contains the following configurations:
 *
 * * MySQL settings
 * * Secret keys
 * * Database table prefix
 * * ABSPATH
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress1');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', '<correct_username>');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', '<correct_password>');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

/**#@+
 * Authentication Unique Keys and Salts.
 *
 * Change these to different unique phrases!
 * You can generate these using the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}
 * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies. This will force all users to have to log in again.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 */
define('AUTH_KEY',         'put your unique phrase here');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'put your unique phrase here');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'put your unique phrase here');
define('NONCE_KEY',        'put your unique phrase here');
define('AUTH_SALT',        'put your unique phrase here');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'put your unique phrase here');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'put your unique phrase here');
define('NONCE_SALT',       'put your unique phrase here');

/**#@-*/

/**
 * WordPress Database Table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each
 * a unique prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix  = 'wp_';

/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 *
 * For information on other constants that can be used for debugging,
 * visit the Codex.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress
 */
define('WP_DEBUG', false);

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

the following php script:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', '<same username as wp-config>', '<same password as wp-config>');
if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

returns `Connected Successfully`

my.cnf contents:

```
[root@deepsleep etc]# cat my.cnf
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Comment: We can not guess your mistake if you don't show us the actual configuration needed for PhpMyAdmin and the one you put in `wp-config.php`.  You should obviously obfuscate parts of it like the password but leave it intact as much as possible.

Comment: what do you mean by showing phpmyadmin configuration. There was no configuration needed. I installed it with yum and it just worked. I am going to add the wp-config stuff in the post.

Comment: I'll wager selinux is getting in the way, because it always seems to.  Also, "permissions on the directory of wp stuff is set to 767 recursively" is wrong on so very, *very* many levels.

Comment: I know, but nothing was working and I read this http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-error-establishing-a-database-connection-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

Check if your mysql server is up and running if everything else is correct. Run the below command,

/etc/init.d/mysqld status

If everything is correct your wordpress should install correctly as sun rises every morning.

Comment: mysqld (pid  8080) is running...

Comment: can you post your my.cnf file?

Comment: I know not of this file. I didn't make/edit this. Where is it located?

Comment: It would be somewhere in `/etc/`.

Comment: edited question.

Comment: Check your /var/log/mysqld.log file for error logs

Comment: tail -n 500 /var/log/mysqld.log  and post the output